# bootstrap carousel add highlight style by clicking on image Items

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap carousel but I have a problem . The images doesn't have link but by clicking on the slide's images , the image become highlighted.This is what I mean :

[image]

How could I remove the highlighted style ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [user-select](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property

```
img{
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```